# C# change date between different formats

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to know if there's a way to change the date format depending on the users local date format setting. The date I will store in the DB it's `YYYY-MM-DD` but the users have different formats, like `DD-MM-YYYY` or `DD.MM.YYYY`. What is a clean, elegant way to ensure that my application always retrives the date in local date format, and SQL server always receives the date in `YYYY-MM-DD` to be stored.

Comment: You should be using a `DATETIME` column type to store dates. If you are not doing so, you should be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> in the DB it's `YYYY-MM-DD`

No. If you do it right the storage in the Db does not have a format. It is stored, for example, as a number.

> What is a clean, elegant way to ensure that my application always retrives the date in local date format

Your application receives it as a binary value too. You have to think about format every time it becomes a string.

> in local date format

For that you could rely on the machine configuration:   `datevalue.ToString()`.

But usually you want to take control:  `datevalue.ToString(specificCultureInfo)`

Answer (score 0):

You should always save the date in a datetime object. To parse a date you can use DateTime.TryParseExcact when you know the date format and TryParse when you want to use your users prefrence. However it whould be nicer to use dedecated date controls to get a date from the user.

Answer (score 0):

A `DateTime` object doesn't have a format. You're probably talking about the string representation of the date.

You can return the date as a string using the user's respective culture settings by calling [**`DateTime.ToShortDateString()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx)

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2012, 01, 01);
string dateStringInCurrentCultureFormat = date.ToShortDateString();
```